# Is total rate of return for a stock posted on financial web sites?

Tags: stocks, investing, rate-of-return

I am a beginner trying to teach myself investing. I have read that it is important to look at the total rate of return for the stock when evaluating it (1, 3, 5 years). I understand the logic behind this but can't find this information readily available on common financial websites (Yahoo finance, Morningstar).

Am I looking in the wrong place or is this info not readily available and I therefore have to do math by myself for the stock I am researching?

Answer (score 3):

It may exist but I do not know of any web sites that provide the one, five and ten year return for any stock of your choosing.

You can create a spreadsheet that does this but you'd have to capture historical data as well as the dividend dates and amounts and that would be quite onerous.

In lieu of the above, I think that the best approach would be a [DRIP calculator](https://www.dividendchannel.com/drip-returns-calculator/).  Enter the stock symbol as well as the beginning and end dates and it will provide the following stats for a $10k investment:

- Start date:
- End date:
- Start price/share:
- End price/share:
- Starting shares:
- Ending shares:
- Dividends reinvested/share:
- Total return:
- Average Annual Total Return:
- Starting investment:
- Ending investment:
- Years:

If the stock pays a dividend, it will provide two such sets of stats:

- Growth of $10,000.00 With Dividends Reinvested
- Growth of $10,000.00 Without Dividends Reinvested

Answer (score 2):

Just MHO (which should be a comment, but is too long, so I made it a Community Wiki) but a beginner should not invest in *individual* stocks.

Mutual funds and ETFs (essentially mutual funds that act like stocks)

1. give you greater diversity, and
2. they display the 10 year growth, which **includes dividends**, and takes into account pesky things like stock splits.

You can then then break down that growth into 1, 3 and 5 year segments.  (Some math is required, but it's a single simple formula, and -- once it's in your spreadsheet you never have to type it in again.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I should have probably formulated my background a bit better. I am a beginner in direct equity investing. I am invested into mutual funds already. Trying to take that next step and start picking individual stocks.

Comment: @myroslav please edit the question to say that.